# Shortcut to "User Profiles" manager under Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, shortcuts, user-profiles, links

I'm searching, from a long time, to create a shortcut to the "User Profiles" manager.

[image]

How is it possible? Windows surely has a link behind the button so why could I not get it?

Comment: "How is it possible? Windows surely has a link behind the button so why could I not get it?" - What a strange argument. Every dialog shown by a program or the OS doesn't have a direct link to it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can directly load the User Profiles dialog by running the following from a command propt:

> rundll32 sysdm.cpl,EditUserProfiles

[Source 1](https://superuser.com/questions/477988/how-can-i-remove-the-home-folder-for-a-deleted-user-on-windows-7/478024#478024)

[Source 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12583349/command-to-open-configure-advanced-user-profile-properties-windows-7)

You can create a shortcut to this if you wanted easily enough by creating a .bat file with that command on it. You need elevate the permissions of the .Bat to that of an Administrator user in order to see all user profiles on the machine.

Since you are an Administrator, going through the control panel, this happens automatically.

Comment: I apologize but it seems to show only the current user. Is this normal? http://i.stack.imgur.com/z5EZe.png
I tried the command on different computers and the result was the same on each computer.

Comment: Thank you! If I run it as administrator, all users are shown. Super User is definitely the best community!